# how to replace "Nothing" cell by last month value

Tags: sql-server-2005, matrix, reporting-services

I am using SSRS develop a report via Matrix.

I sum the product sales qty every month but if some month sale qty is 0, the cell will be `Nothing`.

I'm trying to using `Previous` function to solve problem but this function seems not work for Matrix object.

Is there any way to do this?

1st table is currently report result. 
2nd table is that i want.

[image: Report]

Comment: I think it would make sense to change the SQL query or a stored procedure you use as a dataset source in the way so that it returns the target data you need for the matrix. If you share the SQL statement you use, then someone could help you to adapt it.

Comment: `code`select x.date2 'yyyy/mm'
, x.product_name
, x.Month_sale_QTY
from 
(select Dateadd(d,1-DATEPART(d,a.date),a.date) AS Date2
, a.product_name
, sum(a.sale_qty) as Month_sale_QTY
from a 
group by Dateadd(d,1-DATEPART(d,a.date),a.date)
, a.product_name) as x 
group by x.date2, x.product_name, x.Month_sale_QTY
order by x.Product_name, x.Date2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a table with the structure and content like this:

```
CREATE TABLE a (date Date, product_name NVarchar(20), sale_qty Decimal(10,2))
INSERT INTO a (date, product_name, sale_qty) VALUES ('20130510','product A',1)
INSERT INTO a (date, product_name, sale_qty) VALUES ('20130601','product A',0)
INSERT INTO a (date, product_name, sale_qty) VALUES ('20130501','product B',5)
INSERT INTO a (date, product_name, sale_qty) VALUES ('20140205','product A',1)
INSERT INTO a (date, product_name, sale_qty) VALUES ('20140215','product A',1)
INSERT INTO a (date, product_name, sale_qty) VALUES ('20140202','product B',2)
INSERT INTO a (date, product_name, sale_qty) VALUES ('20140301','product A',0)
```

Then the below sql-statement will work for you (as far as I understood the requirement):

```
SELECT
      y.Date2 AS 'yyyy/mm'
    , y.product_name
    , ISNULL(z.Month_sale_QTY,0) AS Month_sale_QTY

FROM
    (SELECT
          DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, y.StartDate) AS Date2
        , (SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(d,1-DATEPART(d,a.date),a.date) FROM a WHERE DATEADD(d,1-DATEPART(d,a.date),a.date) <= DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, y.StartDate) AND a.product_name = p.product_name AND ISNULL(a.sale_qty,0)<>0 ORDER BY 1 DESC) AS Date3
        , p.product_name
    FROM
        master.dbo.spt_values x
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT Dateadd(d,1-DATEPART(d, MIN(Date)), MIN(Date)) AS StartDate, MAX(Date) AS EndDate  FROM a) AS y
        ON x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, y.StartDate, y.EndDate)
        ,(SELECT DISTINCT product_name FROM a) AS p WHERE x.type = 'P') y
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
          DATEADD(d,1-DATEPART(d,a.date),a.date) AS Date2
        , a.product_name
        , SUM(a.sale_qty) as Month_sale_QTY
    FROM a
    GROUP BY
          DATEADD(d,1-DATEPART(d,a.date),a.date)
        , a.product_name
    ) z ON y.Date3 = z.Date2 AND y.product_name = z.product_name
```

It returns the following:

```
yyyy/mm    product_name         Month_sale_QTY
---------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------
2013-05-01 product A            1.00
2013-06-01 product A            1.00
2013-07-01 product A            1.00
2013-08-01 product A            1.00
2013-09-01 product A            1.00
2013-10-01 product A            1.00
2013-11-01 product A            1.00
2013-12-01 product A            1.00
2014-01-01 product A            1.00
2014-02-01 product A            2.00
2014-03-01 product A            2.00
2013-05-01 product B            5.00
2013-06-01 product B            5.00
2013-07-01 product B            5.00
2013-08-01 product B            5.00
2013-09-01 product B            5.00
2013-10-01 product B            5.00
2013-11-01 product B            5.00
2013-12-01 product B            5.00
2014-01-01 product B            5.00
2014-02-01 product B            2.00
2014-03-01 product B            2.00
```

I'm sure it can be optimized using windowing functions and/or CTE, but as a quick solution this one will work too.

Comment: Hello Alexey, i think i found key point. your solution is great.